# Java Spring IOC bean creation value

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control, spring-bean

I need a `bean` like this

```
<bean id="studentWithSchool" class="com.model.Student" scope="prototype">       
    <property name="school">
        <bean class="com.model.School" scope="prototype"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This is OK.

My problem is I have the student returning from a method from a different bean.

I usually load the bean like this when is a property.

```
<property name='beanProperty' value='#{anotherBean.getBeanProperty()}'/>
```

But in this case I need the new bean itself being set from the other bean method `(School object is returned from another bean method)`.

This is what I try, and of course this is wrong:

```
<bean id="studentWithSchool" class="com.model.Student" scope="prototype" value='#{anotherBean.getBeanProperty()}'>      
    <property name="school">
        <bean class="com.model.School" scope="prototype"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the `studentWithSchool` is created and returned by a method in `anotherBean`. If that's the case, you [can use a factory-method](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-class-instance-factory-method):

```
<bean id="studentWithSchool" factory-bean="anotherBean" factory-method="getBeanProperty" scope="prototype" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are trying to use factory patter with Spring . For that you can use factory bean from spring.

```
<bean id="studentWithSchool" factory-bean="anotherBeanStaticFactory" factory-           method="createBeanProperty" scope="prototype"       
<property name="school">
    <bean class="com.model.School" scope="prototype"/>
</property>
```

For more detail you can use below link :-

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html